# RestKit: how to fetch a simple JSON array of strings?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

How should I use RestKit to fetch a JSON array of strings like this :

```
["Paris", "London", "Brussels", "New York"]
```

I tried to make an object mapping but since there's no key path or attribute, I don't know what to map.

I don't even need a mapping, the result could just be an array or a dictionary. Is there a way to achieve that?

EDIT:

For more info & solution : https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a mapping with a `nil` keypath. This instructs RestKit to directly map the string values into your destination objects. See [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#mapping-values-without-key-paths) reference.

Comment: Wain I m wonder what If I need to do opposite, I mean if I need to send flat array of strings in post service with body like ["123", "123", "123"] ?

Comment: then you shouldn't use RestKit, just use the underlying AFNetworking @AqibMumtaz

Comment: I m using a lot restkit in my app, I need to mange request some how, I just came across to your own comment, just looking into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369558/posting-json-array-of-strings-with-restkit#comment45311998_28369558