# Posting JSON array of strings with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, json, mapping, restkit

I have the following object

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *objectId;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *tags; // array of strings, e.g. @[@"one", @"two"]

@end
```

I would like to POST a request using RestKit (version 0.23) to URL

```
<base_url>/do_something/:objectId
```

The request body should be just a JSON array of strings according to the `tags` property, i.e.

```
["one", "two"]
```

I have a route defined.

```
RKRoute *route = [RKRoute routeWithClass: [MyObject class] pathPattern: do_something/:objectId method: RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute: route];
```

Now, I would like to create a request

```
[objectManager requestWithObject: instanceOfMyObject method: RKRequestMethodPOST path: nil parameters: nil];
```

How should I configure a `[RKObjectMapping requestMapping]` and how should I define a `RKRequestDescriptor` to get the mapping above (JSON array of strings)?

I have tried the following:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addPropertyMapping: [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath: @"tags" toKeyPath: nil]];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping: requestMapping objectClass: [MyObject class] rootKeyPath: nil method: RKRequestMethodAny];
```

However, using `nil` as key path in `RKAttributeMapping` crashes. Using any not-nil value results in request its body is a JSON dictionary

```
{"someKeyPath": ["one", "two"]}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the mapping and descriptor? Show the code you tried and explain what it did wrong.

Comment: @Wain Question edited.

Comment: It's easier to just use NSJSONSerialization in this case

Comment: @Wain What do you mean by "easier" please? Does it mean that it is impossible to configure RKRequestDescriptor to create such request?

Comment: You aren't really doing any mapping. I haven't tried getting a simple array out like you are so I don't know what the exception is, but using NSJSONSerialization to create the body data and then creating a request using RK, adding the body and use RK to send it is a fine solution

Comment: @Cimlman please post solution if you found it, Thanks,

Comment: @Wain could you please past sample code for creating RK request and setting body data in it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe RestKit was designed with the mentality you should be posting an object instead, eg. `{"tags": [ "tag1", "tag2" ]}`. Same with responses; if the body is not an object (and just a raw string or array), RestKit isn't going to handle it well.

That being said, you can serialize the request yourself and post it to the body. For example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"do_something/objectId" parameters:nil] mutableCopy];

[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:doableIds options:0 error:nil]];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
[objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```